# Homepage returning 404 error

Tags: sharepoint-online

I just noticed that the root of my Sharepoint Online website gives a 404 error.
I have several subsites that work just fine, and I can still access all the pages of my site: the only problem is that '/' seems to point to nothing.

How do such a thing happen ? And how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

So to understand correctly:

When you are trying to access https://domain.sharepoint.com/, you are getting 404 error website not found?
When you are trying to access https://domain.sharepoint.com/subodomain, you have no issues?

Before you got the error: have you tried to rename the site? Edit in Designer/VS?
Are you being redirected anywhere?
Is the site in the bin?
Is it listed among site collections?
Do you get the site via Powershell when you write get-sposite?

Can you verify what you have in Trusted Locations under Sharepoint Admin Centre?

Comment: Question 1 and 2, yes. I tried renaming the site, I did use Designer but not VS. I'm not being redirected. I don't have the rights to access the site collection view. But using the REST API, I can perform any action I want on the site with no problem whatsoever. I've made progresses, discovering that the file 'FormServerTemplates/Forms/template.dotx' has been modified and cannot be restituted to its default state. Could it be linked to the issue ?

Comment: I deleted these two files, they can't be restored for some reason. Didn't change anything. And I also don't have access to the Sharepoint Admin Centre.
And to be more precise about the issue, I can access any page of the site at the root of the collection (eg: https://domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx), plus the subsites (eg: https://domain.sharepoint.com/subdomain), but while the '/' path should redirect me to 'SitePages/Accueil.aspx', it just displays '404' instead.

Comment: Alright that answered the question. The 'SitePages/Accueil.aspx' file does not exist. If I replace it with one from another site, then it stops bringing up 404 error and just shows a crash page. I can't restitute the default version for this file unfortunately...

Comment: I think that Microsoft is making backups so if you had some extremely important information there, you can request a restore. However, you will have to agree to restore a whole site collection from a given (recent) date, not just a subsite or .aspx file.

Comment: I'd gladly comply to these conditions... I don't even have anything really important there: the real problem is that my boss won't like the idea of paying the 300 euros it costs to ask Microsoft for such an intervention.

Comment: Verify that but I think it comes under free support. Just open a ticket request from your account and ask. It is free even for trial versions, so why not for you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably someone deleted `Home.aspx`. That's kind of an `index.html` for a sharepoint site. Go to the following URL:
`https://<yourtenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<yoursite>/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx`

Then restore the file from there.